# iOS silver UI elements

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, user-interface

Is there any Apple-provided way to create UI with silver elements, like in iPhoto or WWDC apps? I would like to avoid creating custom UI with custom images. Example:
http://cdn.macrumors.com/article-new/2012/05/wwdc_2012_app.jpg

Comment: have you tried to use the `tintColor` property of the i.e. `UINavigationBar`...?

Comment: tintColor works on ios5 > versions

Comment: There is a bit different gradient in Apple's apps, so tintColor is not enough

Comment: You could subclass `UINavigationBar` and have a custom `CAGradientLayer` property that applied a gradient to the UI element.

Comment: I know how to do it by myself, I've only wondered if it became a part of the SDK

Comment: @Prince, according to the **[Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/tintColor)**, the `tintColor` property is available from iOS2.0 **(!)**.

Comment: are not discussing about UIElement as tintColor was introduced in ios5 for UIElement http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html